# Python/exchangelib - How to access shared public folders and calendars

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

How can I connect to a shared public folder using exchangelib?

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, ServiceAccount, \
    EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone, Configuration, NTLM, CalendarItem, Message, \
    Mailbox, Attendee, Q, ExtendedProperty, FileAttachment, ItemAttachment, \
    HTMLBody, Build, Version

credentials = Credentials(username='DOMAIN\\username', password='password')
config = Configuration(server='server', credentials=credentials, auth_type=NTLM, verify_ssl=False)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='user@email.com', config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

for i in account.root.get_folders():
    print(i)
```

When I run the code above I get the output shown below. I'm pretty sure none of these options correspond to a shared public folder.

> Folder (AllItems)
>
> Folder (Common Views)
>
> Folder (Deferred Action)
>
> Folder (ExchangeSyncData)
>
> Folder (Finder)
>
> Folder (Freebusy Data)
>
> Folder (RCA_EWSSyncTestFolder)
>
> Folder (Recoverable Items)
>
> Folder (Deletions)
>
> Folder (Purges)
>
> Folder (Versions)
>
> Folder (Reminders)
>
> Folder (Schedule)
>
> Messages (Sharing)
>
> Folder (Shortcuts)
>
> Folder (Spooler Queue)
>
> Folder (System)
>
> Tasks (To-Do Search)
>
> Folder (Top of Information Store)
>
> Calendar (Calendar)
>
> Contacts (Contacts)
>
> Folder (Conversation Action Settings)
>
> Messages (Deleted Items)
>
> Folder (Spam)
>
> Messages (Drafts)
>
> Messages (Inbox)
>
> Messages (Archive)
>
> Folder (Suspected Spam)
>
> Folder (Journal)
>
> Messages (Junk E-Mail)
>
> Folder (Notes)
>
> Messages (Outbox)
>
> Folder (Quick Step Settings)
>
> Folder (RSS Feeds)
>
> Messages (Sent Items)
>
> Messages (Sync Issues)
>
> Messages (Conflicts)
>
> Messages (Local Failures)
>
> Messages (Server Failures)
>
> Tasks (Tasks)
>
> Folder (Transport Queue)
>
> Folder (Views)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: any solution for this?