# Python Exchangelib / How to access public folders

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangelib, public-folders

I'm having some problems trying to connect to a public folder with `exchangelib`. I'm using Python 3.6 and exchangelib 1.11.4.

I'm already connected and I'm able to load mails from the inbox.

I'm trying to access the public folders like this:

```
account.public_folders_root.children
```

My problem is that children returns a FolderCollection, and if I call the .len() method it always returns 0, so the FolderCollection is empty; it doesn't find any child folders.

If I execute the following:

```
account.public_folders_root.absolute
```

it returns: `/IPM_SUBTREE`. I'm not sure if that's the right path for my public folders.

Comment: Here is the last time the question got asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958544/python-exchangelib-how-to-access-shared-public-folders-and-calendars (it did not get an answer)

Comment: `FolderCollection` doesn't have a `.len()` method. What did you actually call to get a 0 returned?

Comment: But if `account.public_folders_root.absolute` returns `\IPM_SUBTREE`, then it seems it thinks it's the root folder somehow, which is strange. That path should be reserved for `account.root`, I believe.

Comment: I'm using the __len__() method. So I called myFolderCollectionObject.__len__()

Comment: This is most likely due to the bug reported in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/396. We're going down the wrong folder hierarchy when looking for public folders.